# How do I get powershell or windows terminal to print color text using ansi escape codes?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, command-prompt, ansi-escape

I'm trying to learn to write python code that will output in the terminal different colour text using ansi escape characters. I'm watching a tutorial on python sockets and just learning to communicate between different terminals. I've tried the following on command prompt, powershell and windows terminal and same results.

```
message = "$([char]0x1b)[30;41m YOUR_TEXT_HERE $([char]0x1b)[0m"

print(message)
```

When I try this, the output in the terminal shows

```
$([char]0x1b)[30;41m YOUR_TEXT_HERE $([char]0x1b)[0m
```

I also tried to use this so that the double quotes were in the line

```
message = "$([char]0x1b)[30;41m YOUR_TEXT_HERE $([char]0x1b)[0m"

print('\"'+message+'\"')
```

but it just outputs this

```
"$([char]0x1b)[30;41m YOUR_TEXT_HERE $([char]0x1b)[0m"
```

If I type
`"$([char]0x1b)[30;41m YOUR_TEXT_HERE $([char]0x1b)[0m"`
into the terminal and press enter, it shows correct with red background and black text

I've tried to google and youtube about this but can't seem to find an answer. Please help. Thanks

Comment: `"$([char]0x1b)[30;41m YOUR_TEXT_HERE $([char]0x1b)[0m"` is PowerShell syntax, which only works from within a PowerShell (*.ps1) script of when entered _directly_ into a PowerShell console. When you print it using Python, it is printed literally, because Python doesn't know anything about PowerShell. It doesn't matter that you launched Python from a PowerShell console. Python now "owns" the console and dictates the rules.

Comment: Thanks, as the answer below, \x1b works in python and windows terminal. Any idea how come it works for wt but not powershell and command prompt? Is there a reason that \x1b is recognize by python but only in windows terminal but not in powershell and command prompt? Thanks

Comment: Old versions of command prompt and PowerShell don't support ANSI escape codes required for colorization.

Comment: I updated powershell and it works! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$([char]0x1b)` should be `\x1b` in Python. So this should work:

```py
message = "\x1b[30;41m YOUR_TEXT_HERE \x1b[0m"

print(message)
```

Comment: Thanks this works in windows terminal, though it doesn't work in powershell or command prompt. Thank you!